# Get call notification when a MS Teams user gets/make call from/to PSTN (configured through Direct Routing)

Tags: botframework, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

As per the document it seems like we have to use MS Calling bot endpoint to get the call notifications(i.e. the case when bot is involved in the call ). But in case, when we have used Direct Routing with own SIP Trunks in MS Teams for incoming/outgoing call to PSTN, How can we get notifications like call is being establishing, established, terminated, etc.?

Any suggestion or workaround will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

@Bijay, This is currently not supported but it is in pipeline and should be available in future.